# How to extract the query string from a SQLite object in nodejs?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

How to extract the query string from a `SQLite` object in `nodejs`?

For example if we have this:

```sql
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3';
import { open } from 'sqlite';

const db = await open({
  filename: 'test.db',
  driver: sqlite3.Database
});

var ret = await db.get('SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE id=? AND foo=?', [100, 'bar']);
```

How can we achieve this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE id="100" AND foo="bar"
```

I expect something like this to happen:

```
db.getQueryString();
```

Comment: ret has the query result, so what exactly is your problem?  are you searching for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776205/retrieve-data-from-sqlite-query-node-js

Comment: @nbk as I said, I need to the query built by sqlite as string.

Comment: that is simplestring replacement and the query does that automaticall, so i don't understand what do want with a string or does it come somehow from the datavase. this is very unclear

Comment: The C API has [a way to do it](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/expanded_sql.html) but I suspect the node interface doesn't export a fraction of the functionality of the C version.

Comment: @nbk Of course, placement is not simple, otherwise we would have simply used `foo="bar"` instead of `"foo=?", ["bar"]`. sqlite has an internal control mechanism to escape some characters to make the query secure, I need the same built-in query to insert into the log files when it fails.

Answer (score -1):

es6 string replacement is supporet by nodesjs.

```
var my_id = 100
var my_var = 'bar';
var s = `SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE id="${my_id}" AND foo="${my_var}" `;
console.log(s);
```

But you should prepare your statements to make the secure like https://stackoverflow.com/a/49328621/5193536

Depending if ydo want the strings in the log to be used, for testing, you must add single quotes to the sting above, which the query makes automatically

Comment: This method does not guarantee that it will not have problems with special characters and does not cover security.

Comment: that is why you use the prepared statement and not a sting replacement, but you stated you want to write in a log file, so it is the only way to do it